# jQuery Mobile navigate to alternate aspx

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-mobile

I am porting a jQtouch app to use JQMobile instead. Most of it is moving across fine but there are a couple of bits im having a problem with.

1) in JqTouch i was using

```
$("#approveRequests").bind('pageAnimationEnd', function () { getRequestList(); return false; });
```

to load data when a particular page ( a div in a single html document ) is displayed. I could not get the event working so I decided to move markup from my single index.aspx document into smaller seperate documents.

I tried changing this to:

```
$("#approveRequests").live('pageShow', testMethod);
```

but the event seems to fire as soon as the page loads rather than when the div is displayed

2) after moving the markup for one of the divs in to a seperate page I cant get the app to navigate to it. It just pops up a loading dialog and never does anything.

Here is the markup to create the menu:

```
<div data-role="content">

    <a href="RequestsMaster.aspx" data-role="button">Requests</a> 

    <a href="#invoices"
        data-role="button">Invoices</a> <a href="#expenses" data-role="button">Expenses</a>
    <a href="#timesheets" data-role="button">Timesheets</a> 
    <a href="#holidays" data-role="button">
        Holidays</a> <a href="#about" data-role="button">About</a>

            <a href="#logout" data-role="button"
                data-theme="e" button-icon="delete">Log out</a>
</div>
```

The line im having the problem with is :

```
<a href="RequestsMaster.aspx" data-role="button">Requests</a>
```

The page is in the same folder as the Index.aspx

Is there anything else you need to know?

[image]
This is where its stuck

Comment: Make sure you use alpha3 and jquery 1.5.1

Comment: Thanks, I got it working by adding a ? after the page name. eg RequestsApprove.aspx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seemed to be a problem with the markup of the child page. Not sure exactly what yet. Managed to get it to change page but now there is no styling on the child page

Comment: Make sure the child page contains a `<div data-role="content"></div>` element and that its contents have the appropriate data-role attributes for styling.

Comment: Hi, it looks like a bug in jq 1.4.4. Here is the work around I used... add a "?" at the end of the hyperlink. This tells the jquery mobile that it needs to render a new page but it could be the same page so have it style properly. (if your hyperlinks already have GET variables in your URLs then you are all set.)
Example:
site/mobile/news.html?   (http://forum.jquery.com/topic/switching-pages-new-page-does-not-get-styles)